# Converting from Closed Form

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Let $A(n) = \lfloor n/2+\log_2(n)-\log_2(2) \rfloor$.  Is there an easy way to convert this closed form into a recursive form?  If so, what is the general method, and how might it be applied here.  If it helps, I am familiar with the reverse process of moving toward closed form.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\log_2 (2)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks George.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(n)$ and $A(n+1)$ be the explicit formulas of your above question without replacing $n$.

Simple general approaches for recursive forms could be e.g.

$a(n+1)=a(n)+\left(A(n+1)-A(n)\right)$, $a(1)=A(1)$, $n\geq 1$

or

$a(n+1)=a(n)\cdot\frac{A(n+1)}{A(n)}$, $a(1)=A(1)$, $a(2)=A(2)$, $n\geq 2$.

If you are interested only in the result and not in the mathematical derivation, then you could type your sequence of integers in [OEIS](http://oeis.org). But OEIS does not contain your above sequence.